# Border goes over two rowspans

Tags: html, css

I will show you my problem with an example, here i use on column with a rowspan:

```
<table border="1" style="width:300px">
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2">Familie</td>
  <td id="jill">Jill</td>
  <td>Smith</td> 
  <td>50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="eve">Eve</td>
  <td>Jackson</td> 
  <td>94</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Somehow when i add the css:

```
border-left: 1px solid red;
```

To `#jill` the two rows get a red border: http://jsfiddle.net/hPBds/16/

When i add this css to `#eve` it works how it should, only one border gets this color: http://jsfiddle.net/hPBds/17/

Can somebody say my why this occurs and how i can fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `table`'s `border-collapse` property.  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp

It's set to `collapse`, which is collating the `border`s for `#jill` and the Familie `td`.

Set the `table`'s `border-collapse` CSS to `separate` and that should solve the problem.  Though now you'll have borders on everything else (visibly, borders twice as thick).

```
<table border="1" style="width: 300px; border-collapse: separate;">
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nagra/86jgY/).